# Querying a pandas dataframe with an object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas and a Dataframe and a class with some of the same fields.
Example:

Dataframe:

```py
customer_dict = {"name": ["matthew", "mark", "luke", "john" , "john"], 
                "series_number": [2,2,5,8,8], 
                "personality": ["intj", "entp", "intp", "enfj", "intj"] , 
                "classification" : ["good", "bad", "bad", "good", "bad"]}                                                                          

customer_df = pandas.DataFrame(customer_dict)
```

```py
 customer_df.head()                                                                                                                                   
      name  series_number personality classification
0  matthew              2        intj           good
1     mark              2        entp            bad
2     luke              5        intp            bad
3     john              8        enfj           good
4     john              8        intj            bad
```

Class:

```py
class Customer(): 
         def __init__(self, name, series_number, personality): 
             self.name = name 
             self.series_number = series_number 
             self.personality = personality
```

Notice the Class does not have a classification attribute, but the other attributes are the same as the dataframe's column names.

If I have an object to that class, I want to be able to search the dataframe for the line that matches it so I can get it's classification:

```py
customer = Customer("john", 8, "enfj")

customer_df[customer]
```

Expected result:

```py
      name  series_number personality classification
3     john              8        enfj           good
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Your class **does** have classification attribute. :(

Comment: @harvpan apparently it is an input to the constructor but there is no attribute.

Comment: @rafaelc, there is no default value given. The way OP has initiated the object would/should throw error.

Comment: Yep, I know, but this doesn't make the sentence `Notice the Class does not have a classification attribute,` incorrect haha ;)

Comment: @LucasCorssac To get the line `customer_df[customer]` to work would be troublesome and wouldn't be worth your time. Instead, just extract the logic of slicing to a function (e.g. `filter_customers(customer_df, customer)` and just call that simple line of code.

Comment: Haha, Never the less, there is so much wrong with this code. (ex: `df.DataFrame(customer_dict) `) should be `pd.DataFrame(customer_dict) ` @rafaelc

Comment: Sorry about the mistakes in the code, I ended up typing it directly into question box, I will edit the ones pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple function to enable querying your class instances, instead of doing lengthy masks. This even works for optional attributes.

```
def clsQuery(cls):
    return ' & '.join(["{}=='{}'".format(key, value) 
                       for key, value in cls.__dict__.items()
                      if not value is None])

customer = Customer("john", 8, "enfj", 'good')
customer_df.query(clsQuery(customer))
```

Output:

```
     name   series_number   personality classification
3   john        8                enfj           good
```

You can go beyond to define the function as a class method for ease of access:

```
class Customer(): 
    def __init__(self, name, series_number, personality, classification): 
        self.name = name 
        self.series_number = series_number 
        self.personality = personality

    def query(self):
        return ' & '.join(["{}=='{}'".format(key, value) 
                       for key, value in self.__dict__.items()
                      if not value is None])


customer = Customer("john", 8, "enfj", 'good')
customer_df.query(customer.query())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select rows in a dataframe using multiple conditions. Each must be in parenthesis and & converts to AND.

```
condition = (customer_df['name']=='john') & (customer_df['series_number']==8) & (customer_df['personality']=='enfj')

customer_df = customer_df[condtion]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and kindly give default value to classification

```
class Customer(): 
         def __init__(self, name, series_number, personality, classification=None): 
             self.name = name 
             self.series_number = series_number 
             self.personality = personality 

#initialize the obj
cust = Customer("john", 8, "enfj")

customer_df[(customer_df['name']==cust.name)
            &(customer_df['series_number']==cust.series_number)
            &(customer_df['personality']==cust.personality)]
```

```
    name    series_number   personality classification
3   john    8                    enfj   good
```

Comment: How is it different from my answer?

Comment: the logic is kinda same ,but you didn't tell that classification should have default value other wise it is a syntax error plus you create multiple mask.

Comment: That is an error in OP's code. Not the answer to the question. You are creating multiple masks as well, I am just putting them into variables so that code is more readable. :)

Comment: @harvpan i am not saying your answer is wrong.I am just telling how my answer is different from yours.i was actually posting my answer while you posted yours so I didn't see your answer first

Answer (score -1):

You need to create Boolean mask:

```
mask_name = customer_df['name'] == customer.name
mask_series_number = customer_df['series_number'] == customer.series_number
mask_personality = customer_df['personality'] == customer.personality
```

And then query with masks

```
customer_df.loc[mask_name & mask_series_number & mask_personality]
```

Output:

```
    name    series_number   personality classification
3   john    8               enfj        good
```